# Creating a simple web service for conferences

Tags: php

There was an interesting challenge to create a web service that allows the 2nd people to communicate with each other voice, the voice has to be distorted. Of the languages ​​I use PHP, I would like to know if there are any formulaic solutions / libraries for this task?

Comment: voice has to be distorted ? why ??

Comment: Quick answer: Google it. Second answer: PHP is designed and best as an HTTP web service (through Apache/IIS). You don't want an HTTP web service, so why use something it's not good at? And the fact you'e asking this question means you've one hell of a challenge ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this links:

- Using HTML5:
  http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-speech-input-fields/
- Using Flash:
  //stackoverflow.com/questions/7966044/how-can-i-make-microphone-sound-transfer-from-website-open-in-my-pc-to-websites
- VoicePHP Application: 
  //voicephp.com/howitworks.html

But if you really want to build a communication system you should use VOIP (voice over IP) most successfully communication companies use it //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP

A good open source software which will work perfectly with PHP as well is Asterisk IP PBX
http://www.asterisk.org/